# Google Sheet: How to find Highest Value along with the date for given set of data(date-value pair) in Google Sheet Formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have below data in date-value pair format in Google Sheet:

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/8/2021 | 1301.85 |
| 1/11/2021 | 1303.9 |
| 1/12/2021 | 1320.05 |
| 1/13/2021 | 1291.55 |
| 1/14/2021 | 1287.45 |
| 1/15/2021 | 1270 |

I'm looking for a google sheet formula that will return output: highest value along with its associated date.
That means I'm trying to get the output as below:
`1/12/2021  1320.05`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the **[SORTN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624)** function.
The difference being, by using an `INDEX` formula you need to re-format the column `A` result to a date while using `SORTN` you don't.

```
=SORTN(A2:B,1,0,2,0)
```

[image]

**How the `SORTN` function in our formula works**

- `1` is "the number of items to return" *(since we need just the max we set it to 1)*
- `0` "Shows at most the first n rows" *(this is the so called ties_mode, in our case 0)*
- `2` is "the index of the column containing the values to sort by" *which here is the 2nd column*
- `0` "indicates how to sort the sort_column. TRUE *(or 1)* sorts in ascending order. FALSE *(or 0)* sorts in descending order".

Comment: This solution worked absolutely what I desired, thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Thank you for taking the time to accept.

Comment: Could u please let me know the meaning of 1,0,2,0?

Comment: Please find *"How the SORTN function in our formula works"* within the edited answer. **Also do read** to the [SORTN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624) help page

Comment: Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
=INDEX(SORT(A2:B), 2, 0), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
=index(A2:B,match(max(B2:B),B2:B,0))
```

[image]

Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759445/11225291), you don't need to reformat the date.

Comment: Thank you So Much!!! this approach worked fine for me :)