# Create ARRAY from RANGE & Return MAX Date - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a DataSet that has LanguageCodes in Column A and Dates In Column B.

[image]

I want to be able to get the MAX(DATE) for any given Language. I know this can be done using Filters. However I need to do the function in a google-formula.

I've tried using the FILTER() and MAX() Functions in combination, with no luck - This query returns 0.

`=MAX(ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(B:B,A:A="de-DE")))`

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) formula:

```
=Query(A2:B,"Select A, Max(B) where A <> '' group by A label Max(B) ''",0)
```

[image]

If you want to find the max for a single (specific) language key, then put it as a condition:

```
=Query(A2:B,"Select A, Max(B) where A = 'en-CA' group by A label Max(B) ''",0)
```

but for a single pair of values I would use the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65757817/11225291) instead of `QUERY`.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A2:B; 2; 0); 9^9; 2; 1; 1)
```